# Problem that gltf data output by three.js Exporter cannot be used in model-viewer AR

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, exporter, model-viewer

I want to read the gltf data output by the Three.js Exporter in the model-viewer.

```js
{"asset":{"version":"2.0","generator":"THREE.GLTFExporter"},"scenes":[{"nodes":[0]}],"scene":0,"nodes":[{"mesh":0}],"bufferViews":[{"buffer":0,"byteOffset":0,"byteLength":288,"target":34962,"byteStride":12},{"buffer":0,"byteOffset":288,"byteLength":288,"target":34962,"byteStride":12},{"buffer":0,"byteOffset":576,"byteLength":192,"target":34962,"byteStride":8},{"buffer":0,"byteOffset":768,"byteLength":72,"target":34963}],"buffers":[{"byteLength":840,"uri":"data:application/octet-stream;base64,AACgQAAAoEAAAACAAACgQAAAoEAAAACAAACgQAAAoMAAAACAAACgQAAAoMAAAACAAACgwAAAoEAAAAAAAACgwAAAoEAAAAAAAACgwAAAoMAAAAAAAACgwAAAoMAAAAAAAACgwAAAoEAAAAAAAACgQAAAoEAAAAAAAACgwAAAoEAAAAAAAACgQAAAoEAAAAAAAACgwAAAoMAAAACAAACgQAAAoMAAAACAAACgwAAAoMAAAACAAACgQAAAoMAAAACAAACgwAAAoEAAAAAAAACgQAAAoEAAAAAAAACgwAAAoMAAAAAAAACgQAAAoMAAAAAAAACgQAAAoEAAAACAAACgwAAAoEAAAACAAACgQAAAoMAAAACAAACgwAAAoMAAAACAAACAPwAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAAAAAAAAAAACAvwAAAAAAAAAAAACAvwAAAAAAAAAAAACAvwAAAAAAAAAAAACAvwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgD8AAAAAAAAAAAAAgD8AAAAAAAAAAAAAgD8AAAAAAAAAAAAAgD8AAAAAAAAAAAAAgL8AAAAAAAAAAAAAgL8AAAAAAAAAAAAAgL8AAAAAAAAAAAAAgL8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIC/AAAAAAAAAAAAAIC/AAAAAAAAAAAAAIC/AAAAAAAAAAAAAIC/AAAAAAAAAAAAAIC/AAAAAAAAAAAAAIC/AAAAAAAAAAAAAIC/AAAAAAAAAAAAAIC/AAAAAAAAgD8AAIA/AACAPwAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAgD8AAIA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAIA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAIA/AACAPwAAgD8AAAAAAAAAAAAAgD8AAAAAAAAAAAAAgD8AAIA/AACAPwAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAAAAAAAAAAACAPwAAgD8AAIA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAIA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAIA/AACAPwAAgD8AAAAAAAAAAAAAgD8AAAAAAAACAAEAAgADAAEABAAGAAUABgAHAAUACAAKAAkACgALAAkADAAOAA0ADgAPAA0AEAASABEAEgATABEAFAAWABUAFgAXABUA"}],"accessors":[{"bufferView":0,"componentType":5126,"count":24,"max":[5,5,0],"min":[-5,-5,0],"type":"VEC3"},{"bufferView":1,"componentType":5126,"count":24,"max":[1,1,0],"min":[-1,-1,-1],"type":"VEC3"},{"bufferView":2,"componentType":5126,"count":24,"max":[1,1],"min":[0,0],"type":"VEC2"},{"bufferView":3,"componentType":5123,"count":36,"max":[23],"min":[0],"type":"SCALAR"}],"materials":[{"pbrMetallicRoughness":{"metallicFactor":0,"roughnessFactor":0.9,"baseColorTexture":{"index":0}},"extensions":{"KHR_materials_unlit":{}}}],"textures":[{"sampler":0,"source":0}],"samplers":[{"magFilter":9729,"minFilter":9987,"wrapS":33071,"wrapT":33071}],"images":[{"mimeType":"image/png","uri":"data:image/png;base64,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"}],"meshes":[{"primitives":[{"mode":4,"attributes":{"POSITION":0,"NORMAL":1,"TEXCOORD_0":2},"indices":3,"material":0}]}],"extensionsUsed":["KHR_materials_unlit"]}
```

I used the Three.js Exporter to convert the image data into simple 3D data, and then read it into the model-viewer and tried to display the AR.(iphone & andriod)

The model is output as shown above.

However, I could load it in the model-viewer, but it doesn't work when I press the AR button. Please let me know if there is a problem with the gltf data that is output.